# Troubles with Hibernate configuration with H2

Tags: hibernate, configuration, h2

I'm trying to configure Hibernate to work over H2, but when i call:
    `Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();`
the call for `new Configuration()` outputs the following:
    `מאי 01, 2012 5:10:41 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>

    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}

    מאי 01, 2012 5:10:41 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion

    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.1}

    מאי 01, 2012 5:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>

    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

    מאי 01, 2012 5:10:41 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider

    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist`

But this doesn't stop execution... After this, the call to `.configure()` outputs:
    `מאי 01, 2012 5:14:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure

    INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

    מאי 01, 2012 5:14:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream

    INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

    מאי 01, 2012 5:14:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure

    INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null`

What does these messages mean?

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="database.datatypes.Course"/>
    <mapping class="database.datatypes.Distance"/>
    <mapping class="database.datatypes.ExamRange"/>
    <mapping class="database.datatypes.NumExamsOnDate"/>
    <mapping class="database.datatypes.RecommendedSchedule"/>

</session-factory>
```

One of the classes representing a table:

`@Entity
public class Distance {`

```
private Course courseA, courseB;
private Long MinDistance, Cost;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
@GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
private Long id;


public Distance() {
    super();
}

public Distance(Course courseA, Course courseB, Long minDistance, Long cost) {
    super();
    this.courseA = courseA;
    this.courseB = courseB;
    MinDistance = minDistance;
    Cost = cost;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Distance [courseA=" + courseA + ", courseB=" + courseB
            + ", MinDistance=" + MinDistance + ", Cost=" + Cost + "]";
}

public Course getCourseA() {
    return courseA;
}

public void setCourseA(Course courseA) {
    this.courseA = courseA;
}

public Course getCourseB() {
    return courseB;
}

public void setCourseB(Course courseB) {
    this.courseB = courseB;
}

public Long getMinDistance() {
    return MinDistance;
}

public void setMinDistance(Long minDistance) {
    MinDistance = minDistance;
}

public Long getCost() {
    return Cost;
}

public void setCost(Long cost) {
    Cost = cost;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: It's a normal log output of Hibernate, there is nothing wrong in it. What's exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the messages you mentioned are from INFO level. Messages from this logging level usually lets you know what the underlying framework (here, Hibernate) is doing. So, in that case, everything's fine. If you think theses messages are too disturbing, just change the logging level to something like WARN.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `DEBUG` is even more chatty than `INFO`... If you want less message, you should use `WARN` (only log warnings and errors).

Comment: Ooops, my mistake! You're absolutely right. Anyway, the point is that @Yonatan K can simply change the log level to reduce the verbosity in log files.

Comment: your are right, the point is changing the log level. I guess it makes sense if you update your answer (I didn't want to do that myself as it's your answer).